# File I/O: Array

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def addNumbers(x,y):
        out_file = open("data.txt","w")
        out_file.write(x + "," + y +"\n")
        out_file.close()
        in_file = open("data.txt", "r")
        text = in_file.read()
        in_file.close()
        print text
```

When I run this program I get:

```
x,y
```

Ultimately, I want an array of:

```
x  y
```

And I want to able able to add lines to the file. what am I missing? 
The end result should give me a set of coordinates:

```
x  y
x  y 
x  y
x  y 
etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is "a" as the mode for open which stands for appending. Mode "w" reset the file everytime you open it. It also more efficient if you output all elements at once rather than reopen the file for every element.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Is there a way to get the result to look like an array such that i get my answer w/o a comma:

x  y

Comment: what do you mean like and array? If you don't want comma then just remove it from your code

Comment: If I remove the comma from my code, I get:
xy
I need to have a space, but no comma, between the x and y. The output needs to look like the array that is in the original question.

Comment: Then put a space, not comma out_file.write(x + " " + y +"\n")